# Use of unresolved identifer in an IF statement

Tags: swift, if-statement

Morning

Im working through one of the Udemy AppBrewer courses and I've been looking at how I would solve one of the pieces of work. Ive done what I felt was logical but its returning an error.

Using Swift Im trying to play one of two sounds based on a button being pressed using the the tag value to define the sound to be played. The code works when I don't have any condition created.

Im trying to use an IF statement to review the tag value and then make a decision.

My problem is that I get a 'Use of unresolved identifier' which on review sounds like it doesnt understand one of my variables ( the one in the condition). I cant understand why this would be the case and I dont have enough knowledge on swift to disect it

Works out of the condition just not when Ive put in an IF statement

```
@IBAction func notePressed(_ sender: UIButton) 
{
if sender.tag == 1 {
        let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "note1", withExtension: "wav")
    }
    else {
        let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "note2", withExtension: "wav")
    }
    do {    
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL!)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }

    audioPlayer.play()
}
}
```

This is the error code:

> Error Use of Unresolved identifier "soundURL"
>   "catch" block is unreachable because no errors are thrown into the Do Block

(not sure why my code format is so off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `soundURL` variable is declared inside the `if` and `else` branches. The `do` block is out of the `if` statement, so `soundURL` is *out of scope* in the `do` block, which is why the compiler can't "see" it.

To fix it, declare `soundURL` outside of the `if` statement:

```
let soundURL: URL?
if sender.tag == 1 {
    soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "note1", withExtension: "wav")
}
else {
    soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "note2", withExtension: "wav")
}
```

Now `soundURL` is in the same scope as the `do` block.

Comment: Thanks so when I declare a variable in a loop its usage is restricted to within that loop. However I can declare a variable outside of that loop, assign it a value in a loop and that value then persists

Comment: @JonCassere I'm not sure what you mean by "loops". There are no loops in your code. The programming term "loop" means things like a `for` statement, or a `while` statement. I guess you meant curly braces i.e. `{}`?

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: Yes I agree with your comments. I’m not sure what the right term is maybe condition ? Thanks for your response tho. I did upvote your comment but it said with less than 15 score won’t be show